# adding a column to a dataframe from two Pandas DataFrames and currently using two loops with a conditional: Is there a faster way?

Tags: pandas, loops, iteration, vectorization, apply

I am currently looping through GPS coordinates in a dataframe.  I am using this loop to look into another dataframe with GPS coordinates of specific locations and update the original dataframe with the closest location.  This works fine but it is VERY slow.  Is there a faster way?

Here is sample data:

imports:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
import pandas as pd
from geopy import distance
```

Create sample df1

```
gps_points = [Point(37.773972,-122.431297) , Point(35.4675602,-97.5164276) , Point(42.35843, -71.05977)]
df_gps = pd.DataFrame()
df_gps['points'] = gps_points
```

Create sample df2

```
locations = {'location':['San Diego', 'Austin', 'Washington DC'],
        'gps':[Point(32.715738 , -117.161084), Point(30.267153 , -97.7430608), Point(38.89511 , -77.03637)]}
df_locations = pd.DataFrame(locations)
```

Two loops and update:

```
lst = [] #create empty list to populate new df column
for index , row in df_gps.iterrows(): # iterate over first dataframe rows
    point = row['points'] # pull out GPS point
    closest_distance = 999999 # create container for distance
    closest_location = None #create container for closest location
    for index1 , row1 in df_locations.iterrows(): # iterate over second dataframe
        name = row1['location'] # assign name of location
        point2 = row1['gps'] # assign coordinates of location
        distances = distance.distance((point.x , point.y) , (point2.x , point2.y)).miles # calculate distance
        if distances < closest_distance: # check to see if distance is closer
            closest_distance = distances # if distance is closer assign it
            closest_location = name # if distance is closer assign name
    lst.append(closest_location) # append closest city
df_gps['closest_city'] = lst # add new column with closest cities
```

I'd really like to do this in the fastest way possible.  I have read about the vectorization of pandas and have thought about creating a function and then using apply as mentioned in [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) however I need two loops and a conditional in my code so the pattern breaks down.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Are your dataframes are really Pandas dataframe or Geopandas dataframe with a geometry column?

Comment: just pandas.  just like the sample data.  The real question is optimizing the loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) from Scipy:

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

# Extract lat/lon from your dataframes
points = df_gps['points'].apply(lambda p: (p.x, p.y)).apply(pd.Series)
cities = df_locations['gps'].apply(lambda p: (p.x, p.y)).apply(pd.Series)

distances, indices = KDTree(cities).query(points)

df_gps['closest_city'] = df_locations.iloc[indices]['location'].values
df_gps['distance'] = distances
```

You can use `np.where` to filter out distances that are too far away.

For performance, check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67134845/15239951) for a similar problem with 25k rows for `df_gps` and 200k for `df_locations`.

Comment: Corralien.  Thank you.  Perfect response and thank you for the link to the article I wish I had found before posting.

Comment: Curious though how does the KDTree deal with earth geometry?  If I understand the method right it takes the coordinates into a 2-dimensional plane and then selects the nearest neighbor rather than do any true geospatial distance calculations?  That is why the distance returned is not in miles or like value.  Have you noticed projection errors with this method?

Comment: Although the solution works in some cases it will not in all cases.  This page helps https://kanoki.org/2019/12/27/how-to-calculate-distance-in-python-and-pandas-using-scipy-spatial-and-distance-functions/

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html might help those out there too.

Comment: Thanks i'll take a look and try to post a complete solution here too.

Comment: The goal is too find nearest neighbors so the distance between two points is not really false even if the projection is not right. The distortion should be minimal.

Comment: If you want to use sklearn, choose BallTree instead of DistanceMetric.

Comment: I'd think so as long as the points are near each other but just thinking it through straight line distance is much different than having to traverse a globe.

Comment: unless we think the world is flat ;)

Comment: It depends on your projection. That's why I asked you if you used GeoPandas. I guess you use `WGS84`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780614/how-to-calculate-minimum-distance-using-lat-lon-data-in-python

Comment: BallTree adds the haversine distance capability so I think that should work.  Thank you again for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the insight of Corralien the final answer in code:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree, DistanceMetric

points = df_gps['points'].apply(lambda p: np.radians((p.x, p.y))).apply(pd.Series)
cities = df_locations['gps'].apply(lambda p: np.radians((p.x, p.y))).apply(pd.Series)
dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')
tree = BallTree(cities, metric=dist)
dists, cities = tree.query(points)
df_gps['dist'] = dists.flatten() * 3956
df_gps['closest_city'] = df_locations.iloc[cities.flatten()]['location'].values
```

Comment: Nice work. I updated your post to include modules from `sklearn` to be reproducible by other users. +1 x 2

Comment: no issues I can accept yours.